# How do you know exactly what causes the form not to be valid while processing form with model

Tags: django-models, django-forms

Hey Mentors and Teachers, we appreciate having you, please help a young one here in this industry having not much experience this is one of my common challenges since I am still trying new ways, here I am using a model to save a form and also model form without having to use the form in the template. I am sure using the model form directly would have solved it quickly but I want the ability to be able to style my form, especially each individual field,
the version being used in this is django 3.1
Help me know how to make this code work

```
class Order(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('New', 'New'),
        ('Accepted', 'Accepted'),
        ('Completed', 'Completed'),
        ('Cancelled', 'Cancelled'),
    )

    user = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    payment = models.ForeignKey(Payment, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    order_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    address_line_1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address_line_2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    order_note = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    order_total = models.FloatField()
    tax = models.FloatField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS, default='New')
    ip = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=20)
    is_ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


    def full_name(self):
        return f'{self.first_name}'
```

and here is a view that is am using:

```
def place_order(request, total=0, quantity=0,):
    current_user = request.user

    # If the cart count is less than or equal to 0, then redirect back to shop
    cart_items = CartItem.objects.filter(user=current_user)
    cart_count = cart_items.count()
    if cart_count <= 0:
        return redirect('store')

    grand_total = 0
    tax = 0
    for cart_item in cart_items:
        total += (cart_item.product.price * cart_item.quantity)
        quantity += cart_item.quantity
    tax = (2 * total)/100
    grand_total = total + tax

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Store all the billing information inside Order table
            data = Order()
            data.user = current_user
            data.first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            data.last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            data.phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
            data.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            data.address_line_1 = form.cleaned_data['address_line_1']
            data.address_line_2 = form.cleaned_data['address_line_2']
            data.country = form.cleaned_data['country']
            data.state = form.cleaned_data['state']
            data.city = form.cleaned_data['city']
            data.more_address_details = form.cleaned_data['more_address_details']
            data.order_note = form.cleaned_data['order_note']
            data.order_note = form.cleaned_data['order_note']
            data.order_total = grand_total
            data.tax = tax
            data.ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
            data.save()
            # Generate order number
            yr = int(datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y'))
            dt = int(datetime.date.today().strftime('%d'))
            mt = int(datetime.date.today().strftime('%m'))
            d = datetime.date(yr,mt,dt)
            current_date = d.strftime("%Y%m%d") #20210305
            order_number = current_date + str(data.id)
            data.order_number = order_number
            data.save()

            order = Order.objects.get(user = current_user, is_ordered = False, order_number = order_number)
            context = {
                'order': order,
                'cart_items': cart_items,
                'total': total,
                'tax': tax,
                'grand_total': grand_total,
                
                }
            return render(request, 'orders/payments.html', {'context': context})
        else:
            return redirect('checkout')

            
    else:
        return redirect('store')
```

and here is what is in the template:

```
def place_order(request, total=0, quantity=0,):
    current_user = request.user

    # If the cart count is less than or equal to 0, then redirect back to shop
    cart_items = CartItem.objects.filter(user=current_user)
    cart_count = cart_items.count()
    if cart_count <= 0:
        return redirect('store')

    grand_total = 0
    tax = 0
    for cart_item in cart_items:
        total += (cart_item.product.price * cart_item.quantity)
        quantity += cart_item.quantity
    tax = (2 * total)/100
    grand_total = total + tax

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Store all the billing information inside Order table
            data = Order()
            data.user = current_user
            data.first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            data.last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            data.phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
            data.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            data.address_line_1 = form.cleaned_data['address_line_1']
            data.address_line_2 = form.cleaned_data['address_line_2']
            data.country = form.cleaned_data['country']
            data.state = form.cleaned_data['state']
            data.city = form.cleaned_data['city']
            data.more_address_details = form.cleaned_data['more_address_details']
            data.order_note = form.cleaned_data['order_note']
            data.order_note = form.cleaned_data['order_note']
            data.order_total = grand_total
            data.tax = tax
            data.ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
            data.save()
            # Generate order number
            yr = int(datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y'))
            dt = int(datetime.date.today().strftime('%d'))
            mt = int(datetime.date.today().strftime('%m'))
            d = datetime.date(yr,mt,dt)
            current_date = d.strftime("%Y%m%d") #20210305
            order_number = current_date + str(data.id)
            data.order_number = order_number
            data.save()

            order = Order.objects.get(user = current_user, is_ordered = False, order_number = order_number)
            context = {
                'order': order,
                'cart_items': cart_items,
                'total': total,
                'tax': tax,
                'grand_total': grand_total,
                
                }
            return render(request, 'orders/payments.html', {'context': context})
        else:
            return redirect('checkout')

            
    else:
        return redirect('store')
```

I AM ALWAYS BLOWNED BY THE KIND OF PEOPLE WHO ALWAYS HELP WITHOUT EXPECTING ANYTHING IN RETURN, REALLY THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found where the error was, had forgotten to add the name of a form field "more_address_details" in the template